# AutoField is not reducing the length of column

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.9, django-3.2

I am trying to create auto increment field for tiny integer like int(3).

If I try `AutoField`, it generates length of 11. If I use `max_length`, migration ignores it.

`SmallIntegerField` gives int(6) without auto increment.

My model definition:

```
class tblroles(models.Model):
    role_id = SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="role_id")
    name = CharField(max_length=20)
    is_active = BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Which database backend are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't come with a ***`tinyint`*** field. But, you can create a custom auto-incrementing auto-field by overriding the [**`db_type(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type) method as

```
from django.db.models import SmallAutoField


class TinyAutoField(SmallAutoField):

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "tinyint AUTO_INCREMENT"
```

#### Usage

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    id = TinyAutoField(
        primary_key=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}"
```

**PS**: This solution is perfectly working in **MySQL 8.0**

Answer (score 1):

`SmallIntegerField` is `smallint` (maximum signed value `32767`, display width `6`) in MySQL.

I suppose you want `tinyint` (maximum signed value `127`, display width `3`) in MySQL.

```py
class TinyAutoField(models.SmallAutoField):

    def db_type(self, connection):
        if connection.vendor == 'mysql':
            return 'tinyint AUTO_INCREMENT'
        return super().db_type(connection)

    def rel_db_type(self, connection):
        if connection.vendor == 'mysql':
            return 'tinyint'
        return super().db_type(connection)
```

Usage:

```py
class tblroles(models.Model):
    # role_id = SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="role_id")  # Change this
    role_id = TinyAutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="role_id")        # to this
    # ...
```

---

But if you want literal `int(3)` (maximum signed value `2147483647`, display width `3`) in MySQL.

```py
class AutoField(models.AutoField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.display_width = kwargs.pop('display_width', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        if connection.vendor == 'mysql' and self.display_width:
            return 'int(%s) AUTO_INCREMENT' % self.display_width
        return super().db_type(connection)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if self.display_width:
            kwargs['display_width'] = self.display_width
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Usage:

```py
class tblroles(models.Model):
    # role_id = SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="role_id")
    role_id = AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="role_id", display_width=3)
```